# To print a 3D string in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

Hello can anyone please let me know a function for 3D printing in OpenGL. I had to print a string and was using glutBitmapCharacter() but this is not printing it.

Thankx in advance. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very good tutorial (*link removed as it eventually pointed to a malware site*) (video and text version). There are source files: text3d.h/cpp, charsets.
You can include this files to your project. After that you can draw 2d/3d text:
    t3dDraw3D("My text", 0, 0, 0.2f);
It's very easy to use.

Warning: I had a problem with this site few times (some AV warnings and redirects - propably DNS system of this site has been hacked). You can see some information of security risk. IT'S FAKE! If you have this fake infos, type address: http: // www . videotutorialsrock . com , next click Lesson 8: Drawing Text.

(sorry for ma bad English)

Answer (score 2):

OpenGL doesn't handle [3D printing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_printing).  You may wish to look into a [MakerBot](http://www.makerbot.com/).

On a more serious note I assume you meant extruded text rendering.  Take a look at [some of these](http://www.opengl.org/resources/features/fontsurvey/).

Answer (score 1):

You probably meant representing the text in 3D... No, OpenGL does not have a way of doing it natively, but using some extra well known libraries you can achieve the effect. There's an exact [tutorial on that on NeHe](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/lesson.asp?lesson=14).